# How to make the preprocessing layers part of the CNN model?

Tags: tensorflow, keras

My goal is to make the preprocessing layers part of the CNN model.

This is because some images have different size (258,320) and (322,480) and I would like to resize it both when training and predicting.

So, I am following the [docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/images/data_augmentation).

The problem is:

1. when I tried to do `seq_1.summary()` it throws error `This model has not yet been built. Build the model first by calling` build() `or by calling the model on a batch of data.`

   The solution is to do `seq_1.build(input_shape=(None,150,150,3))`. But this does not solve the problem because now the model expects the input to be 150,150,3 instead of 258,320 or 322,480.
2. after running `build` method, I tried to do `seq_1.fit(x=X_train, y=y_train, callbacks=callbacks)`.

It throws error

```
ValueError: Data cardinality is ambiguous:
  x sizes: 258, 258, 258, 258, 258, 258, 258, 258, 258, 258, 258, 258, 258, 258, 258, 258, 258, 258, 258, 258, 258, 258, 258, 322, 258, 258, 258, 258, 258, 258, 258, 258, 258, 258, 258, 258, 258, 258, 258, 322, 258, 258, 258, 258, 258, 258, 258, 258, 258, 258, 258, 
...
258, 258
  y sizes: 9773
```

The code

```
callbacks = [
    # Stop training when a monitored metric has stopped improving
    EarlyStopping(
        monitor='val_loss', patience=20, min_delta=0.0001, mode='min', 
        restore_best_weights=True),
    # Reduce learning rate when a metric has stopped improving.
    ReduceLROnPlateau(
        monitor='val_loss', factor=0.2, 
        # We believe RreduceLROnPlateau should have less patience than EarlyStopping
        patience=10, min_delta=0.0001, min_lr=0.001),
    # Callback that streams epoch results to a CSV file
    CSVLogger('./results/train.log'),
    # Callback to save the Keras model or model weights at some frequency.
    ModelCheckpoint(filepath="seq_1.h5", monitor='val_loss', save_best_only=True)
]

resize_and_rescale = tf.keras.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.Resizing(150,150),
    tf.keras.layers.Rescaling(1./255)
])

data_augmentation = tf.keras.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.RandomFlip(mode="horizontal_and_vertical"),
    # tf.keras.layers.RandomRotation(0.2)
])

img_shape = (150, 150, 3)

seq_1 = tf.keras.Sequential([
    # standardize images.
    resize_and_rescale,
    
    # Data augmentation is inactive at test time so input images will only be
    # augmented during calls to seq_1.fit
    data_augmentation,

    # we are not sure how more filters help to classify image
    # but our philosophy are these:
    # 1. first layer extract features (edges, noise, etc) from raw image, 
    # which is noisy (a image contain object that is not relevant)
    # 2. second layer combine features (some edges) to get a shape e.g circle
    # 3. we believe 2 layers are enough to create features.
    Conv2D(
        # strides=1, so it overlap itself and takes advantage of correlation
        # to create a shape.
        filters=32, kernel_size=(3,3), strides=1, 
        activation='relu', input_shape=img_shape, use_bias=True),
    # pool_size=(2,2), strides=2, 
    # so it does not overlap itself.
    MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2), strides=2),
    
    Conv2D(
        filters=64, kernel_size=(3,3), activation='relu', strides=1, 
        input_shape=img_shape, use_bias=True),
    MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2), strides=2),
    
    Flatten(),
    
    Dense(units=len(df_b['kind'].unique()), activation='relu'),
    
    # softmax makes it easier to interpret (if we use threshold tuning)
    # we will use argmax to classify.
    # but, argmax can't be used for backpropagation because the derivative is 0
    Activation(activation='softmax')
])

seq_1.summary()
```

The code to train

```
seq_1.compile(
    optimizer='adam',
    loss=tf.keras.losses.CategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True),
    # reference: https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/41921/sparse-categorical-crossentropy-vs-categorical-crossentropy-keras-accuracy
    metrics=[tf.metrics.CategoricalAccuracy()]
)

seq_1.fit(x=X_train, y=y_train, callbacks=callbacks)
```

EDIT

Code to load images

```
def load_images(df):
    paths = df['path'].values
    X = []
    
    for path in paths:
        raw = tf.io.read_file(path)
        img = tf.image.decode_png(raw, channels=3)
        X.append(img)
        
    y = df['kind'].cat.codes
    
    return X, y
```

Comment: Use seq_1.build(input_shape=(None, None, None, 3))

Comment: @V.M The data cardinality error persisted. Perhaps the problem is the `def load_images(df)`? The return `X` have 2 different image shape `258,320` or `322,480`.

Comment: use the `ragged tensor` as I have answered in your other question.